# Fluent Validation set validator doesn't work in List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I have problem with wtih fluent validation not working on List.
I did it as it is in documentation ( https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/collections.html)
But it doesn't work while on single validation of AddressForCreation it does work.
Link to whole project: https://github.com/KryspinTrawnik/CafeMVC
I have entity OrderForCreationVm which has list of AddressForCreationVm.

**Please note I shortened OrderForCreation for clear view

```
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.Configuration.Annotations;
using CafeMVC.Application.Interfaces.Mapping;
using CafeMVC.Application.ViewModels.Customer;
using CafeMVC.Application.ViewModels.Products;
using FluentValidation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CafeMVC.Application.ViewModels.Orders
{
    [AutoMap(typeof(CafeMVC.Domain.Model.Order))]
    public class OrderForCreationVm : IMapFrom<CafeMVC.Domain.Mo..del.Order>
    {
        
        [Ignore]
        public List<AddressForCreationVm> Addresses { get; set; }

        public void Mapping(Profile profile)
        {
            profile.CreateMap<CafeMVC.Domain.Model.Order, OrderForCreationVm>().ReverseMap()
                .ForMember(d => d.OrderedProductsDetails, s => s.MapFrom(opt => opt.Products));
        }

    }

    public class OrderForCreationValidator : AbstractValidator<OrderForCreationVm>
    {
        public OrderForCreationValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull();
            RuleForEach(x => x.Addresses).SetValidator(new AddressForCreationValidator());
        }

    }
    
}
```

AddressForCreationVm;

```
using AutoMapper;
using CafeMVC.Application.Interfaces.Mapping;
using FluentValidation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CafeMVC.Application.ViewModels.Customer
{
    public class AddressForCreationVm : IMapFrom<CafeMVC.Domain.Model.Address>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string BuildingNumber { get; set; }

        public int FlatNumber { get; set; }

        public string Street { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }

        public List<AddressTypeVm> AllAddressTypes { get; set; }

        public string Btn { get; set; }

        public void Mapping(Profile profile)
        {
            profile.CreateMap<AddressForCreationVm, CafeMVC.Domain.Model.Address>().ReverseMap();

        }
    }

    public class AddressForCreationValidator : AbstractValidator<AddressForCreationVm>
    {
        public AddressForCreationValidator()
        {
            string[] availableZipcodes = new string[] { "LE1 ", "LE2", "LE3", "LE4" };
            RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull();
            RuleFor(x => x.AddressTypeId).NotNull();
            RuleFor(x => x.BuildingNumber).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(255);
            RuleFor(x => x.ZipCode).NotEmpty().Must(x => availableZipcodes.Any(prefix => x.StartsWith(prefix))).Length(7).When(x => x.AddressTypeId == 2);
            RuleFor(x => x.City).Equal("Leicester").When(x => x.AddressTypeId == 2);
            RuleFor(x => x.Country).MaximumLength(255).NotEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

I made unit test for testing if RuleFor(x => x.ZipCode)  is working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CafeMVC.Application.ViewModels.Customer;
using CafeMVC.Application.ViewModels.Orders;
using CafeMVC.Domain.Model;
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.TestHelper;
using Xunit;

namespace CafeMVC.Tests.FluentValidationTests
{
           [Theory]
        [InlineData("LE12 7EH")]
        [InlineData("LE5 7EH")]
        public void AddressForCreationValidatorUnderOrderShowErrorWIthWrongZipCode(string zipCode)
        {
            //Arrange
            OrderForCreationValidator validator = new();
            OrderForCreationVm order = new()
            {
                Addresses = new()
            {
                GetAddressForTests()
            }
            };
            order.Addresses[0].ZipCode = zipCode;
            //Act
            var result = validator.TestValidate(order);
            //Assert
            result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.Addresses[0].ZipCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately test shows this:
[image]

I tried to change order validator to child rules like from documentation but it didn't work.
I specially wrot unit tests to check Addess validator itself and that's working properly.
I looked for similar issues on stackoverfolw but all of them are from older versions of Fluentvalidation or doesn't apply to my case.

Comment: Instead of using `RuleForEach` and `SetValidator`, try `RuleFor` and `SetCollectionValidator`